# How to assign varaible in ng-model on input based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to assign ng-model variable based on condition. For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.model[multilang]" >
```

`$scope.multilang` can be `"ENG","JP"(languages)` or `false`. For example, if `multilang = "ENG"` and user type in input `"Hello"`,the result will be

```
item.model = {ENG:"Hello"}
```

The problem is when `$scope.multilang = false` , I want the result would be

```
item.model = "Hello"
```

I can't find a way to achieve above result. I think one solution is changing ng-model based on `$scope.multilang` so when it's false,it will change ng-model of input to be = `ng-model="item.model"` but I don't know how to do this.

**EDITED**
I thought of one solution:

```
<input ng-if="multilang" type="text" ng-model="item.model[multilang]" >
<input ng-if="!multilang" type="text" ng-model="item.model" >
```

but there is better way to achieve ?

[-----plnkr example-----](https://plnkr.co/edit/WT8qNaZbTvKAfhKTjbz9?p=preview)

Comment: show how is your $scope.multilang is defined initially ?

Comment: @SidBhalke it is in the same controller.

Comment: @SidBhalke I created plnkr,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is very flexible and powerful framework. You should use custom directive and ngModel's getter/setter option.

**Directive without ngModel's getter/setter may look like this:**

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="val" 
       multilang="multilang" 
       multilang-model="item.model">
```

**Directive code:**

```
 .directive('multilang', [function(){

    return {

      restrict: "A",

      require: "ngModel",

      scope: {
        multilang: "=",
        multilangModel: "="
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){

        ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function()){

          var value = ngModel.$modelValue;

          if(scope.multilang !== false) {

            if(typeof scope.multilangModel == 'undefined')
              scope.multilangModel = Object.create(null)

            scope.multilangModel[scope.multilang] = value

          }

          else {

             scope.multilangModel = value

          }
        })
      }
    }
 }])
```

[--forked plunkr--](https://plnkr.co/edit/js6lnYEiqKQDLZSNWabC?p=preview)

**In case of using ngModel's getter/setter**

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="val" 
       multilang="multilang" 
       multilang-model="item.model" 
       ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
```

**Directive code:**

```
 .directive('multilang', [function(){

    return {

      restrict: "A",

      scope: {
        multilang: "=",
        multilangModel: "=",
        val: "=ngModel"
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attr){

        scope.val = function(newValue) {

          if(scope.multilang !== false) {

            if(typeof scope.multilangModel == 'undefined')
              scope.multilangModel = Object.create(null)                

            return arguments.length ? (scope.multilangModel[scope.multilang] = newValue) : scope.multilangModel[scope.multilang];

          }

          else {

             return arguments.length ? (scope.multilangModel = newValue) : scope.multilangModel;

          }
        }
      }
    }
 }])
```

[--forked plunkr--](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5qfU1Tw0zRWZZy9z9k2?p=preview)

In my opinion, second one is better. It has two way binding with `item.model` and changes `input` value when `item.model` was changed in other place of code.

Comment: Can you describe the second one?, I don't understand what 'newValue' is. I already read doc but still don't get it. what 'newValue' is assigned? and why you have to require 'ngmodel' in the second one? Thanks

Comment: second code must to be edited. I will edit in 10 min

Comment: Done.  A getter/setter is a function that returns a representation of the model when called with zero arguments, and sets the internal state of a model when called with an argument. It's sometimes useful to use this for models that have an internal representation that's different from what the model exposes to the view.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you so much :) But I don't understand when the function called with argument or not?. Can you explain me or give me a resource?.

Comment: When function called as `Setter` - `newValue == ngModel.$modelValue`. When function called as `Getter` - returned value changes ngModel.$viewValue

Comment: Thank you so much.I really applicated it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input ng-show="multilang" type="text" ng-model="item.model[multilang]" >
<input ng-hide="multilang" type="text" ng-model="item.model" >
```

Comment: Yes,I thought of this, but There is so many ones. There is another way?

Comment: please make a plnkr. That will be helpful. Maybe directive will help.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a **built-in** testing sandbox, no need to use plnkr, jsfidlle, pastebin, or write it on your bathroom walls...